# OpenLdap exception : bdb unable to join the environment

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

In Openldap after making changes when i am trying to run below command

```
slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
```

I am end up with the below exceptions

```
562f60eb bdb_db_open: database "dc=tm,dc=tel,dc=ro": unclean shutdowed; attempting recovery.
562f60eb bdb_db_open: database "dc=tm,dc=tel,dc=ro": recovery skipped-only mode. Run manual recovery if errors are encountered.
562f60fd bdb(dc=tm,dc=tel,dc=ro): unable to join the environment
562f60fd bdb_db_open: database "dc=tm,dc=tel,dc=ro" cannot be opened. Restore from backup!
562f60fd backend_startup_one (type=bdb, suffix="dc=tm,dc=tel,dc=ro")open failed! (11)
slap_startup failed (test would succeed using the -u switch)
```

Can any one tell what wrong i am doing?

Comment: is `slapd` already running? This is the typical error you get in this case.

Comment: no Ldap is not running when i am trying to start ldap i am getting 

Checking configuration files for slapd:                    [FAILED]
562f6c02 ldif_read_file: Permission denied for "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif"
slaptest: bad configuration file!

Comment: It sounds like you're running slaptest as an ordinary user instead of as root. try as root? Generally I would expect all the files/directories to end up owned by `openldap`

Comment: I am login as a root only.

Comment: ehhh… it sounds like you've run `slaptest -f -F` as root, which has created files owned by root, and now it's likely that trying to startup slapd is changing the user to `openldap` which doesn't have access to the config files anymore. You should make sure that all the files under `/etc/openldap/slapd.d` are owned by the user that the service `slapd` runs under (I've mentioned `openldap` as a user as it's a likely account name)

Comment: Ok What i did ,i removed to /etc/openldap and configuration and retry now its starting .But now i am getting another issue when i am connecting ldap from Apache directory,after making connection Root DSE have no any child so any import of ldif file i am getting openldap “no global superior knowledge”

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93507/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-petesh).